# ios - load new view as modal and keep gcd async code running

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using dispatch_async to run a section of code (a specific method) on a parallel queue (a series of connectivity checks, not really important)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
        [self connectivityChecks];
});
```

Everything is working fine with this while on the current view controller.

What I would like to do (if possible) is to load a new view controller modally and keep that section of code running, as it would fire some events on the new view controller based on the checks it's running. Using this to load new view.

```
CustomViewController *customLoader = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
[customLoader setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:customLoader animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is it at all possible to have this working this way?
If not, how could I achieve something along these lines?

Comment: I think you need an other class instance to be in charge of the async task. You could create a new before creating your customLoader which will have an observer of an event fired by the async task.

Comment: So, you mean having a separate class with all the async checks, initialize it (new instance) and then call up the new view?
But wouldn't the instance get discarded along all other view controller variables as soon as I load up a new one?

Comment: @CanATAC creating a custom class for the checks and having it load asynchronously worked like a charm! Can you please write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: oh ? thanks ! didn't have time to check your first comment...but glad you did it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transform my comment into a more detailed answer :

1. In your CustomViewController, add a notification observer, named, well, say : 'com.myapp.connected'
2. In the same CustomViewController, don't forget to remove the observer when it disappears
3. Create a new custom class, say : 'TaskManager'
4. Insert a method in charge to launch an async task in it

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
   [self connectivityChecks];
   ```

   });
5. In connectivityCheck, post a notification named 'com.myapp.connected' when the connection operation succeeded
6. From your calling class, create an instance of 'TaskManager'
7. From your calling class, Create an instance of CustomViewController.